# Excel VBA Form Show Unique Entries with Time Calculation in Listbox

Tags: excel, vba, time, listbox, unique

I would like to ask your help about my query below. I have here 2 different forms. Form 1 for saving entries. For saving entries, I already have code. It's already working. Form 2 is a form to display data from excel with time calculation as a desired output. Please see images as it could help.

Data in Excel Sheet1:

```
Date      || Project ID || Implementation Area  || Start Time   || End Time     || Status
8/28/2023 || 1145544    || Arizona              || 8:00:03 AM   || 9:15:17 AM   || For Approval 1
8/28/2023 || 1157788    || Arizona              || 9:15:20 AM   || 12:00:19 PM  || For Approval 1
8/28/2023 ||LUNCH BREAK ||                      || 12:00:18 PM  || 1:00:00 PM   || LUNCH BREAK
8/29/2023 || 1145544    || Arizona              || 1:00:01 PM   || 3:00:00 PM   || For Approval 2
8/29/2023 || 1145544    || Arizona              || 3:30:07 PM   || 3:40:40 PM   || COMPLETED
8/30/2023 || 1157788    || Arizona              || 3:41:00 PM   || 3:50:00 PM   || For Approval 2
9/1/2023  || 1157788    || Arizona              || 4:00:00 PM   || 4:30:45 PM   || COMPLETED
9/2/2023  || 1233343    || New York             || 9:05:17 AM   || 11:30:20 AM  || For Approval 1
9/2/2023  ||LUNCH BREAK ||                      || 12:00:00 AM  || 1:00:00 PM   || LUNCH BREAK
9/2/2023  || 1233343    || New York             || 1:45:01 PM   || 2:45:30 PM   || For Approval 2
9/2/2023  || 1233343    || New York             || 3:00:00 AM   || 3:22:00 AM   || COMPLETED
9/2/2023  || 1422457    || Louisana             || 3:50:00 PM   || 4:12:00 PM   || For Approval 1
9/3/2023  || 1422457    || Louisana             || 10:18:03 AM  || 11:15:17 AM  || For Approval 2
9/4/2023  || 1422457    || Louisana             || 4:15:20 PM   || 4:35:19 PM   || COMPLETED
```

Form 1

[image: Form1]

Form 2

[image: Form 2]

This is my code for Form 2

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim colimplementationArea1 As Variant, colimplementationArea2 As Variant, colimplementationArea3 As Variant
Dim colStatus1 As Variant, colStatus2 As Variant, colStatus3 As Variant

Set Rng = Range("C:C") 'project id
Set rng1 = Range("D:D") 'implementation area
Set rng2 = Range("E:E") 'start time
Set rng3 = Range("F:F") 'end time
Set rng3 = Range("G:G") 'status

colimplementationArea1 = "Arizona"
colimplementationArea2 = "New York"
colimplementationArea3 = "Louisana"
colStatus1 = "For Approval 1"
colStatus2 = "For Approval 2"
colStatus3 = "COMPLETED"


'i lack codes for Listbox1 and Listbox2 that will display data from Excel Sheet1:

'--------Listbox1
'Unique Project ID     |    Area of Implementation     |    Total Hours Worked from Approval 1 to COMPLETED per Unique ID

'Calculation:
'***total hours worked will add the time of Start Time and End Time of For Approval 1 + Start Time and
' + End Time of For Approval 2 + Start 'Time and End Time of COMPLETED***



'--------Listbox2
'Unique Area of Implementation | Total Hours Worked using different Unique IDs containing same Area | Avearage Hours

'Calculation:
'***using Sheet1, we will be adding the total hours of the 2 Unique IDs 1145544 and 1157788 for Arizona from
'Start Time to End Time then divide it by 2 (since there are 2 unique ids)
'There's nothing to calculate for the rest of the Areas because they contain 1 unique ID only***


'Apologies... I really don't know where to start for the calculations of my listboxes
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you think someone wants to retype your data? See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld    posted it to explain that the output is based on data. so, u mean i should not post the excel part? nobody might understand what my posted forms are displaying. i am emphasizing the time started and ended. do you mean that i should not include the excel part?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld in my deleted post i was told that i lack info of what i am asking. i am correcting of my learned lesson now to post full of info not lacking. its what i am doing ryt now. but if u will insist that i should remove the excel part, then i will. anyway, here, we always learn a lesson and we are always corrected

Comment: Your data should be posted as text which can be easily copy pasted so that it can be used to try to replicate your problem. There's guidance as to how to do that in the link I provided. It is certainly okay to provide a screenshot of your desired results. But the data should provided as text.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, copy. i will revise this. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems a rather complex problem to code and output the results in List Boxes, but here's one way to keep it relatively organized and flexible enough for changes to be made.

I use a Class Module and Dictionary objects to organize the data and create output arrays

***Class Module***
*Rename as indicated in Comments*

```
'rename cProjectData
Option Explicit
Private pID As Variant
Private pDt As Date
Private pIArea As String
Private pStartTime As Date
Private pEndTime As Date
Private pStatus As String
Private pCol As Collection

Public Property Get ID() As Variant
    ID = pID
End Property
Public Property Let ID(value As Variant)
    pID = value
End Property

Public Property Get Dt() As Date
    Dt = pDt
End Property
Public Property Let Dt(value As Date)
    pDt = value
End Property

Public Property Get IArea() As String
    IArea = pIArea
End Property
Public Property Let IArea(value As String)
    pIArea = value
End Property

Public Property Get StartTime() As Date
    StartTime = pStartTime
End Property
Public Property Let StartTime(value As Date)
    pStartTime = value
End Property

Public Property Get EndTime() As Date
    EndTime = pEndTime
End Property
Public Property Let EndTime(value As Date)
    pEndTime = value
End Property

Public Property Get Status() As String
    Status = pStatus
End Property
Public Property Let Status(value As String)
    pStatus = value
End Property

Public Property Get TotHrs() As Date
    TotHrs = pTotHrs
End Property
Public Property Let TotHrs(value As Date)
    pTotHrs = value
End Property

Public Property Get Col() As Collection
    Set Col = pCol
End Property

Public Function addColItem(value)
    pCol.Add value
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pCol = New Collection
End Sub
```

***User Form Module***
*Note that a lot of your declarations are not necessary in this implementation*
*Be sure to set the `Reference` as indicated in the comments*

```
'Add Reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
'   for early binding to Dictionary object

Option Explicit
    'should always be at the start of any VBA module
    'set Tools/Options/Editor/Code Settings/Require variable declaration
    'be sure to declare **ALL** variables
    
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim TotalHours As Date
Dim I As Long, j As Long
Dim k, V
Dim sKey As String

'more descriptive names might be useful in debugging
'  and an array will both limit the appropriate ranges
'  and process much faster

  Dim vData As Variant

'since this code is in a sheet module, no need to
'  specifically reference this worksheet
vData = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp))

'Trim the strings
'may not be needed in your real data
    For I = 1 To UBound(vData, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(vData, 2)
            vData(I, j) = Trim(vData(I, j))
        Next j
    Next I

'Group data by Project Name and by Implementation area
Dim dProj As Dictionary
  Dim KeyDProj As Variant
    
'Create Class object to store the data
  Dim cProj As cProjectData

'iterate through the data and classify it
Set dProj = New Dictionary

For I = 1 To UBound(vData)
 If Not vData(I, 6) = "LUNCH BREAK" Then
    Set cProj = New cProjectData
    With cProj
        .Dt = vData(I, 1)
        .ID = vData(I, 2)
        .IArea = vData(I, 3)
        .StartTime = vData(I, 4)
        .EndTime = vData(I, 5)
        .Status = vData(I, 6)
    End With
    
    KeyDProj = cProj.ID
    
    If Not dProj.Exists(KeyDProj) Then
        cProj.addColItem cProj
        dProj.Add Key:=KeyDProj, Item:=cProj
    Else
        dProj(KeyDProj).addColItem cProj
    End If
    
 End If
Next I

'Access the dictionary and summarize the results
'for ListBox 1 into an array
    Dim vResL1 As Variant
ReDim vResL1(0 To dProj.Count, 1 To 3)

'Headers
    vResL1(0, 1) = "Project Name"
    vResL1(0, 2) = "Implementation Area"
    vResL1(0, 3) = "Total Hours"
I = 1
For Each k In dProj.Keys
    TotalHours = 0
    For Each V In dProj(k).Col
        TotalHours = TotalHours + V.EndTime - V.StartTime
        vResL1(I, 1) = V.ID
        vResL1(I, 2) = V.IArea
    Next V
    vResL1(I, 3) = TotalHours
    I = I + 1
Next k

'summarize vResL1 by averaging TotalHours
Dim dImplArea As Dictionary
Set dImplArea = New Dictionary
    dImplArea.CompareMode = TextCompare
    
For I = 1 To UBound(vResL1, 1)
    sKey = vResL1(I, 2)
    
    If Not dImplArea.Exists(sKey) Then
        dImplArea.Add Key:=sKey, Item:=Array(1, vResL1(I, 3))
    Else
        V = dImplArea(sKey)
        V(0) = V(0) + 1
        V(1) = V(1) + vResL1(I, 3)
        dImplArea(sKey) = V
    End If
    vResL1(I, 3) = Format(vResL1(I, 3), "hh:mm:ss")
Next I

Dim vResL2 As Variant
ReDim vResL2(0 To dImplArea.Count, 1 To 3)

'Headers
    vResL2(0, 1) = "Implementation Area"
    vResL2(0, 2) = "Total Hours Worked:"
    vResL2(0, 3) = "Average Hours:"
    
I = 1
    For Each V In dImplArea.Keys
        vResL2(I, 1) = V
        vResL2(I, 2) = Format(dImplArea(V)(1), "hh:mm:ss")
        vResL2(I, 3) = Format(CDate(dImplArea(V)(1) / dImplArea(V)(0)), "hh:mm:ss")
        I = I + 1
    Next V
    
'write results to the listboxes
With Me.ListBox1
    .ColumnCount = 3
    .ColumnWidths = "75;110;100"
    
    .List = vResL1
End With

With Me.ListBox2
    .ColumnCount = 3
    .ColumnWidths = "110;100;75"
    .List = vResL2
End With

End Sub
```

***Output from your Data***
[image]

Comment: i will try this. brb

Comment: i tried Adding Microsoft Scripting Runtime using Tools->References from the VB menu. i created a class module named cProjectData and copied ur class module code to it.i tried to put  dim cProjectData as Scripting.Dictionary under Option Explicit and called the module in userform_activate but i got an error that says expected variable or procedure, not module in the line call module1.tried to put dim cProjectData as Scripting.Dictionary just above Dim TotalHours As Date.i run it and listboxes were blank.may i know what have i missed

Comment: @Shiela `dim cProjectData as Scripting.Dictionary` is wrong and makes no sense to me.  It is not a variable that needs to be declared. `cProjectData` is the Class Module. As I show in my code, you `Dim cProj As cProjectData` in your main code body.

Comment: @Shiela For more information about Class Modules see this article by the late Chip Pearson on [Classes in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Classes.aspx). And I have provided you all of the code that I used to obtain the results I showed. When you select from the main menu to `Insert Class Module` you are not given any choice as to where to put it, so that shouldn't be an issue. Probably you can replace your Userform code with what I provided. I can't screenshare with you.

Comment: @ Ron Rosenfeld, ty. yes looking into it

Comment: i did not change anything in the code. there was just a missing code in the last part that needs to be copied and pasted. then there it is!! thank you soooo much!!!!

Comment: @ Ron Rosenfeld. I have additional question, 1 last. how to format the time that deletes AM/PM? Sample, start time is 15:10:00 and end time is 15:15:50. when subtracted it should return 00:05:50. as of now it is returning 12:05:50.ty

Comment: @Shiela Sorry, I overlooked that part. Code now edited and corrected to show proper format. That is done by formatting the appropriate cells in the array being written to the ListBox, using the VBA `Format` function.

Comment: @ Ron, wow, this code is awesome!!! ty!

Comment: hi, i am thinking that it is really a good idea to put a button thats called Stats (for Statistics) which opens another form of 2 graphs. is there a way u could put a code that converts the result for vResL1 and vResL2 into graph 1 and graph 2 respectively? thank you

Comment: @Shiela I'm sure it could be done. But that is a separate question and not something that can be answered in a comment. If you are unable to figure it out, I suggest you post your efforts as a new question in accordance with the guidelines of this site, and I'm sure someone will be able to assist you.

Comment: yes, understood. i will do it.

Comment: hi... thank you so much for this code, i already used it in my workbook. theres another form that i need to show the same except that it will not be unique entries anymore like this. instead, it will be all of the entries still with calculation. is there a part of your code in ur answer that i need to delete to remove filtering the unique entries and just show all the the entries with calculation? i have another question for it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77207203/populate-listbox-with-time-calculation-after-combox-change thank you