# Populate ListBox with Time Calculation after ComBox change

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, listbox

I have here a simple userform that populates listbox according to combobox change.

Code for unique list in combobox:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'used this code to get a dynamic combobox unique Task list in Sheet1 Column A
    'but I wonder why there is an extra space after the last item in combobox
    Dim v, e
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A10000")
        v = .value
    End With
    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        .CompareMode = 1
        For Each e In v
            If Not .Exists(e) Then .Add e, Nothing
        Next
        If .Count Then Me.ComboBox1.List = Application.Transpose(.Keys)
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: userform1]

Raw Data Update (added Columns F and G in excel)
***Please don’t mind how the columns are arranged as they have a purpose.

```
Task     ||ID    ||PARAGRAPH #|| START        ||END       || Month    || Name
Writing  ||4823  ||  1        ||13:00:00      ||13:15:00  || January  || Larry
Reading  ||4823  ||  1        ||13:16:00      ||13:18:00  || February || Larry 
Writing  ||4823  ||  2        ||13:20:00      ||13:30:00  || March    || Larry
Reading  ||4823  ||  2        ||13:31:00      ||13:50:00  || April    || Larry
Writing  ||4824  ||  1        ||14:00:00      ||14:10:00  || October  || Cole
Reading  ||4824  ||  1        ||14:11:00      ||14:14:00  || October  || Cole
```

Image of Raw (added columns F and G):
[image: image of raw updated]

***This is my updated desired outcome for combobox change with current Month and column Name (does not need to have a Total time column in excel sheet, only in listbox):

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If ComboBox1.value = "Writing" And Month = current month Then '***
    'if values are present then
    'calculate time (end - start) for Writing rows
    'populate listbox of Writing entries with Total Time Column, Month Column, Name Column
    'no need to populate start and end cols       

    'if there are no values found in Sheet1
    'ListBox1 is just blank

ElseIf ComboBox1.value = "Reading" and Month = current month Then '***
    'if values are present then
    'calculate time (end - start) for Reading rows
    'populate listbox of Reading entries with Total Time Column, Month Column, Name Column
    'no need to populate start and end cols     

    'if there are no values found in Sheet1
    'ListBox1 is just blank
End If
End Sub
```

***Updated ListBox desired Outcome for Writing and current Month and column Name:

[image: writing outcome]

***Updated ListBox desired Outcome for Reading and current Month and column Name:

Reading:
[image: reading outcome]

Note: Month format is Now, "mmmm"
Name will not be required in filtering. Just needed to be brought up with the list.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77037452/excel-vba-form-show-unique-entries-with-time-calculation-in-listbox) also has calculation but it is for unique IDs. Current question does not need to be unique as long as listbox populates according to combobox selection. Answer 1 here satisfies the display after combobox change but no time calculation or Total column (end-start) in the listbox. Answer 2 before the Edit has time calculation but no month and column name; Edited answer in Answer 2 returns blank listbox. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you only extract parts of the respective range, usually an array is the best approach. But loading the list box using its `List` property, **does not allow placing headers**. Only if you have another (probably hidden) sheet, or another free range in the same sheet where to paste the extracted array and linked the resulted range to the list... What do you prefere?

Comment: @FaneDuru i can make static headers through labels list will be fine

Comment: So, if I will create a piece of code able to only return the necessary rows for the two cases (Reading and Writing) will it be enough?

Comment: @FaneDuru i will choose a shorter code. answer below though is almost perfect. the time calculation are in decimals

Comment: Then, try the code I posted...

Comment: Just about populating the combo box i.e. getting rid of the blank item: wrap the *If* statement in the loop in another *If* statement: `If Len(e) > 0 Then: If Not .Exists(e) Then .Add e, Empty: End If`. Nitpicking here, but `Nothing` is used with objects and is kind of inappropriate here. Also, to reference the column dynamically. you could e.g. use `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion: With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1): v = .Value: End With: End With`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 yes, thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, test the next code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, count As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary one
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  
      arr = sh.Range("A2:F" & lastR).value 'place the range in an array for faster processing
      count = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR), ComboBox1.value) 'count the specific string occurrences
      If count > 0 Then
        ReDim arrFin(1 To count, 1 To UBound(arr, 2) - 1) 'redim the final aray
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
            If arr(i, 1) = ComboBox1.value Then
                k = k + 1
                For j = 1 To UBound(arrFin, 2)
                    If j = UBound(arrFin, 2) Then
                        arrFin(k, j) = Format(arr(i, j + 1) - arr(i, j), "hh:mm:ss")
                    Else
                        arrFin(k, j) = arr(i, j)
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
        Next i
      Else
        listBox1.Clear
      End If

     With listBox1
        .ColumnCount = UBound(arrFin, 2)
        .List = arrFin
     End With
End Sub
```

Of course, you have to set each columns width according to your needs..

**Edited**:

The next version will filter the returned array on the sixth column (current months), too, also bringing the seventh column. **Take care to have STRINGS months name in G:G column**:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, count As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
  Dim arrMonths: arrMonths = Split("January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December", ",")
  Dim curMonth As String: curMonth = arrMonths(Month(Date) - 1)
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary one
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row in the range to be processed
  
      arr = sh.Range("A2:G" & lastR).Value 'place the range in an array for faster processing
      
      'calculate the necessary array elements:
      count = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR), ComboBox1.Value, sh.Range("F2:F" & lastR), curMonth)

      If count > 0 Then
        ReDim arrFin(1 To count, 1 To UBound(arr, 2) - 1) 'redim the necessary array to keep the rows to be loaded in list box
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
            If arr(i, 1) = ComboBox1.Value And arr(i, 6) = curMonth Then
                k = k + 1
                For j = 1 To UBound(arrFin, 2)
                    If j = UBound(arrFin, 2) - 2 Then
                        arrFin(k, j) = Format(arr(i, j + 1) - arr(i, j), "hh:mm:ss")
                    ElseIf j = UBound(arrFin, 2) - 1 Then
                        arrFin(k, UBound(arrFin, 2) - 1) = curMonth
                    ElseIf j = UBound(arrFin, 2) Then
                        arrFin(k, UBound(arrFin, 2)) = arr(i, j + 1)
                    Else
                        arrFin(k, j) = arr(i, j)
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
        Next i
      Else
        ListBox1.Clear: Exit Sub
      End If

      With ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = UBound(arrFin, 2)
        .List = arrFin
      End With
End Sub
```

If you need to collect more columns, please place them before the last FOUR ones. A piece of code is designed according to the question. If a new column have to be returned, the code can be adapted relatively easily, but if you want another one and then other two, it will be difficult to be handled.

If you will add all of them before the last four, as mentioned above, it will work well after adapting only the next issues:

- extend the range to be processed up to the last column (`arr = sh.Range("A2:x" & lastR).value`)
- identify the column keeping the month names and use it in the second part of `count` calculation (`sh.Range("x2:x" & lastR), curMonth`)
- use the above mentioned column NUMBER in the array processing (`arr(i, colNo) = curMonth`).

Comment: let me try this too i will be back

Comment: i like this because it is shorter. there are 5 columns in the listbox display for your answer. first column is for reading/writing. second column is ID. third is paragraph number. 4th column has decimal values. 5th column in listbox returns the time calculated. however, there is an extra column the fourth that are in decimals. it should not be there

Comment: @Shiela It could not be so... `arrFin` has a column less than `arr`. This can be possible maybe **if there is a hidden column you forgot about it**, I think. Is your fist range column A:A and the last E:E, as shown in the picture?

Comment: yes sorry i experienced the stackoverflow offline maintenance 1 hr ago. ur answer is already working. i changed the range from a2:f to a2:e. i would like to add an F column for months January, February, etc. And i would like to filter Reading/Writing in current month which is September. where should i insert the filtering of month to your code. should it be in the line `If arr(i, 1) = ComboBox1.value and arr(i,6) = Format(Now, "mmmm")`?

Comment: @Shiela I think it is time to learn how to ask a question... It my reflect your real need. We here do not support projects, we only answer questions **as they are** and you must evaluate it only against it. Even supposing that I will make an exception, **I cannot understand what you want**. You are talking about "from a2:f to a2:e", this means a column less, not more. Supposing that you mixed the ranges, the solution to be chosen is your localization dependent. How your standard date for today looks?

Comment: apologies i will be updating my post, standard date is month word only January, February ... September like that for column F. let me update it

Comment: i already updated it in asterisks. whats added is the result with the current month.ty

Comment: @Shiela  Please, test the updated answer and send some feedback. I mean, version posted after **Edited**...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255485/discussion-between-shiela-and-faneduru).

Comment: @Shiela I am afraid I am not able to keep the step with your new questions. What you try doing is not bringing clarifications in each edit. After answering the question **as it has been formulated** you started requiring different things. In the community way of working, what you did should be asked in **a new question**. You were talking about an extra column, in an above placed comment (months name) and I placed another answer. It did not work (probably) because you did not specify what format the month name has. I assumes strings. You did not clarify this aspect in the new editing, neither.

Comment: @Shiela Then, you introduced a new column, **without mentioning if the name should also be considered in the filtering algorithm, or only bringing it into the list box**. I would like to remind you that the need of editing is necessary only **to clarify issues**. Required in comments or you appreciate that they will help us understanding better the question. Instead of this, you added new requirements...

Comment: i edited my question to close the needs for this question. if i will be making a new one i am afraid it will be tagged as duplicate since same images will be shown. so i made the edits once and for all

Comment: @Shiela Please, test the last (adapted) version. When require different issues after the code has been design, it is not so simple to adjust its initial logic to the new requirements. Usually, the code is design based on the clear understanding of the question requirements. It is good to firstly learn, **HOW TO ASK**!

Comment: do i have to call this sub combobox1_change7columns? because the change does not take effect everytime i switch reading/writing in combobox. if i will put the code to combobox1_change, i receive an error type mismatch for line .columncount = Ubound(arrFin,2)

Comment: You need to simple change the sub name, to be the necessary event. I do not remember of such a code line containing what you show. You must replace comboVal with Combobox1.Vakue. in two places. I tested it on a sheet list box.

Comment: @Shiela I adapted the code to do what you need, only copying it from above. I did it on my mobile phone and I hope I could do it properly. Please, send some feedback after testing it. And I think is time to try understanding the code and understand by yourself where and why a problem may come from. The, you should cultivate the habit to **always use Option Explicit on top of every module**. In this way VBA would warn that the respective variable was not declared...

Comment: i replaced comboval with Combobox1.value. still i am getting an error here saying type mismatch in the line `.ColumnCount = UBound(arrFin, 2)` under `With ListBox1`

Comment: alright be right back. i will be sending you a feedback right after

Comment: @Shiela This is strange. Theoretically it means that `arrFin` has not been loaded. I will adapt it to previously check that.

Comment: @Shiela Do you have AnyDesk installed and accept a connection? I can spend now about 10 minutes, being near a computer. I will see what's happening in your installation and understand what's happening. I adapted the code to stop before the erroring sequence, if the array has not been loaded (no any occurrence of the necessary filtering conditions.

Comment: @Shiela I'm leaving now...

Comment: i am still getting the error in the same line. yes i have anydesk on my phone but none for my company laptop. we can continue tomorrow. it really is strange

Comment: @Shiela Did you refresh the page (this one) and copied the last version? Does it have the code line `ListBox1.Clear:Exit Sub`?

Comment: i put the `ListBox1.Clear:Exit Sub` before `.ColumnCount` still there is no display in listbox. the type mismatch error is gone though and everytime i switch the combobox, H column has data and vanishes

Comment: @Shiela This is wrong. You must not play with pieces of code you do not understand. In the way you used it, the list box **will never be loaded**! I did not recommend placing this code line **somewhere**... I only asked if it exists! Where to exist? In the above code... You should look in your code and find it. If not, this only should mean that **you do not use the updated one**. /This code line is placed between `Else` and `End If`. A better idea, if you do not understand the code, would be to **copy it as it is** and **after that** try understanding what it does...

Comment: i did copy the same code.but the listbox is still blank. i just did transfer of that Exit sub line to see whats going to happenbut it is just the same blank listbox and H has vanishable data. no more mismatch error. i copied ur edited code back still listbox just blank.

Comment: @Shiela  I tested the code on my laptop, so it's working. Without seeing what's happening in your installation, it is difficult to understand what's happening. Let us try the next way, but you must stay here. I do not like wasting my time... Let us go back to the chat window. Is that OK to you?

Comment: i sent u a msg in chat

Comment: @Shiela I wrote on the chat window, but for messages there you are not notified. You should frequently look at that page, I think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255514/discussion-between-shiela-and-faneduru).

Comment: sent u a msg....

Comment: @Shiela What do you mean by that? What and where did you send such a "msg"? In the chat window there is no any comment since two days, on mail I did not received anything, too.

Answer (score 1):

Find the Code below, it will show only relevant items matching the criteria selected in the Combo-Box.

Code is located in a few Sub-routines within the User-Form Module.
Detailed explanation inside the code's comments.

**Code** (tested)

```
Option Explicit

Dim LBDataArr                   As Variant
Dim CBDataArr                   As Variant
Dim TaskSelectedStr             As String

' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

TaskSelectedStr = Me.ComboBox1.Value  ' save in User-Form Public variable

' ~~ Call Sub that loads only relevant Array items to List-Box, by matching the searched String in the current Combo-Box ~~~
LoadRelevantItemsToListBox

End Sub

' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

' ~~~ Call Sub that saves the data in "Sheet1" to arrays ~~~
ReadSheet1ToArray
    
   
With Me.ComboBox1
    .Clear
    .List = CBDataArr
End With

' --- populate List-Box ---
With Me.ListBox1
    .Clear
    .List = LBDataArr
End With

End Sub

' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Sub ReadSheet1ToArray()

'======================================================================================================================
' Description : Sub reads all rows in "Sheet1" worksheet, to 'LBDataArr' 2-D array, and unique values of "Task" in
'               'CBDataArr' array.
'
' Caller(s)   : Sub 'UserForm_Initialize' (in this module)
'======================================================================================================================

Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long, ArrIndex As Long, MatchRow As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' === Save "Materials DB" worksheet fields in 'TempArr' 2-D Array  ===
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    LBDataArr = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(LastRow, "E")).Value  ' save entire "Sheet1" worksheet contents in 2-D array
    
    ReDim CBDataArr(1 To LastRow)
    ArrIndex = 0
    
    ' --- Loop over LB Array and save only unique values in column A ---
    For i = 1 To UBound(LBDataArr, 1)
        If LBDataArr(i, 1) <> "" Then ' include only rows with text in them
            MatchRow = Application.Match(LBDataArr(i, 1), CBDataArr, 0)
            If IsError(MatchRow) Then
                ArrIndex = ArrIndex + 1
                CBDataArr(ArrIndex) = LBDataArr(i, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
  
    If ArrIndex > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve CBDataArr(1 To ArrIndex)
    End If
End With


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Sub LoadRelevantItemsToListBox()

'======================================================================================================================
' Description : Sub scans through the entire 'LBDataArr' (read from "Sheet1" worksheet).
'               Per record tries to match the record's data with the values entered in 'Combo-Box1'
'
' Caller(s)   : ComboBox1_Change (Combo-Box Change event in this Module)
'======================================================================================================================

Dim i As Long, j As Long, LastRow As Long, Col As Long, ArrIndex As Long, MatchRow As Variant
Dim tempArr As Variant


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' ~~~ Call Sub that reads all "Sheet1" to 'LBDataArr' 2-D Array ~~~
ReadSheet1ToArray

tempArr = LBDataArr ' save contents of array in 'Temp' array

ReDim LBDataArr(1 To UBound(tempArr, 1), 1 To 5) ' reset Array

ArrIndex = 0
   
' === loop through arrays >> faster ===
For i = 1 To UBound(tempArr, 1)
    If tempArr(i, 1) = TaskSelectedStr Then
        ' make sure current 'row' passes searched criteria --> add to Array (and List-Box)
        ArrIndex = ArrIndex + 1
        
        ' - I added the columns one by one in case you want to manipulate the daa in one of the columns -
        LBDataArr(ArrIndex, 1) = tempArr(i, 1) ' TASK
        LBDataArr(ArrIndex, 2) = tempArr(i, 2) ' ID
        LBDataArr(ArrIndex, 3) = tempArr(i, 3) ' PARAGRAPH #
        LBDataArr(ArrIndex, 4) = Format(tempArr(i, 4), "h:mm:ss") ' START
        LBDataArr(ArrIndex, 5) = Format(tempArr(i, 5), "h:mm:ss") ' END
    End If
Next i

' at least 1 record match the criteria in 'Task' Combo-Box
If ArrIndex >= 1 Then
    ' ~~~ Nice TRICK to redim first Dimension of 2-D array ~~~
    tempArr = LBDataArr
    ReDim LBDataArr(1 To ArrIndex, 1 To UBound(LBDataArr, 2))
    For i = 1 To ArrIndex
        For Col = 1 To UBound(LBDataArr, 2)
            LBDataArr(i, Col) = tempArr(i, Col)
        Next Col
    Next i
    
    With Me.ListBox1
        .Clear
        .List = LBDataArr
    End With
     
Else ' no result match
    Me.ListBox1.Clear

    MsgBox "No matches for the criteria entered in 'Task' Combo-Box '", vbCritical, "Search Null"
End If


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: let me try this be ryt back.

Comment: when run, it is getting the results however, the time here are all in decimals.

Comment: @Shiela check the edited code, you can use `Format(tempArr(i, 4), "h:mm:ss")` to format as Time

Comment: ty. yes this loads the start and end columns.  however, i was looking for the total time column after paragraph # column just like my desired outputs in my post.

Comment: @Shiela look at your post "Current question does not need to be unique as long as listbox populates according to combobox selection" and the code above does that.

Comment: yes thanks. i updated the post ty