# How to Populate ListBox2 with Average Total Time without Unique IDs

Tags: excel, vba, time, listbox, average

I have here a simple Excel Sheet with data below.

[image: sheet1]

Excel Raw Text

```
YEAR    ID  Work        Time_In     Time_Out    Total_Hours
2023    111 Carpenter   11:00:00    12:00:00    1:00:00
2023    111 Painter     8:00:00     8:30:00     0:30:00
2023    112 Dancer      9:00:00     10:25:00    1:25:00
2023    113 Singer      10:00:00    11:10:00    1:10:00
2023    113 Singer      11:00:00    11:20:00    0:20:00
2023    113 Carpenter   13:00:00    13:10:00    0:10:00
2023    114 Painter     13:40:00    14:00:00    0:20:00
2023    114 Singer      14:40:00    15:35:00    0:55:00
2024    111 Carpenter   11:00:00    11:10:00    0:10:00
```

My post is almost the same with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77037452/excel-vba-form-show-unique-entries-with-time-calculation-in-listbox). But for my current post (this question), I do not have unique IDs in the ID column. IDs can repeat with different Works.

This is my form:
[image: form]

I have managed to get the number of entries (in labels) per Work using this code below.

```
Option Explicit
Sub firstlistdisplay()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim Work() As Variant
    Dim Year() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim dict As Object, key As Variant
    
    Year = Array("2023", "2024")
    Work = Array("Carpenter", "Painter", "Dancer", "Singer")
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'Initialize Dictionary
 
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        key = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value & "_" & ws.Cells(i, 3).Value & "_" & ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
        If Not dict.Exists(key) Then
            dict.Add key, 1
        End If
    Next i
        For j = LBound(Year) To UBound(Year)
            Dim TotalCount As Long
            TotalCount = 0
            For k = LBound(Work) To UBound(Work) 'Loop through Work
                Dim iCarpenter As Long
                Dim iPainter As Long
                Dim iDancer As Long
                Dim iSinger As Long
                
                iCarpenter = 0
                iPainter = 0
                iDancer = 0
                iSinger = 0
                
                For Each key In dict.Keys
                    If InStr(key, "Carpenter") > 0 Then
                        iCarpenter = iCarpenter + 1
                    ElseIf InStr(key, "Painter") > 0 Then
                        iPainter = iPainter + 1
                    ElseIf InStr(key, "Dancer") > 0 Then
                        iDancer = iDancer + 1
                    ElseIf InStr(key, "Singer") > 0 Then
                        iSinger = iSinger + 1
                    End If
                Next key
                Me.Label1.Caption = iCarpenter
                Me.Label2.Caption = iPainter
                Me.Label3.Caption = iDancer
                Me.Label4.Caption = iSinger
            Next k
        Next j
End Sub
```

However, for the desired output in the form image above, I do not know how to code for it.

Please advise. Thank you..

Comment: The total number of entries is 8, but there are 9 rows in your table / listbox1.

Comment: @taller oops. maybe my calculation in my code is wrong. :( please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using two Dict objects to summarize data

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, Work, Labels
    Dim arrList(), i As Long
    Dim cntDict As Object, sumDict As Object, key As Variant
    ' Label1~Label4 is in same order as Work
    Work = Array("Carpenter", "Painter", "Dancer", "Singer")
    Labels = Array("lab_Carpenter", "lab_Painter", "lab_Dancer", "lab_Singer")
    Set cntDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'Initialize Dictionary
    Set sumDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        key = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
        If Not cntDict.Exists(key) Then
            cntDict.Add key, 1
            sumDict.Add key, ws.Cells(i, 6).Value
        Else
            cntDict(key) = cntDict(key) + 1
            sumDict(key) = sumDict(key) + ws.Cells(i, 6).Value
        End If
    Next i
    ReDim arrList(cntDict.Count, 1 To 3)
    arrList(0, 1) = "Work"
    arrList(0, 2) = "Total_Hours"
    arrList(0, 3) = "Average"
    For i = 0 To UBound(Work)
        key = Work(i)
        arrList(i + 1, 1) = key
        arrList(i + 1, 2) = Format(sumDict(key), "h:mm:ss")
        arrList(i + 1, 3) = Format(sumDict(key) / cntDict(key), "h:mm:ss")
        ' Predefined lables name with array
        Me.Controls(Labels(i)).Caption = cntDict(key)
        ' If label controls name follow a pattern         
        ' Me.Controls("lab_" & key).Caption = cntDict(key)
    Next
    With Me.ListBox2
        .ColumnCount = 3
        .List = arrList
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: let me try this brb...

Comment: hi, apologies if I have to ask this because I do not know how to get the counts if my labels are named differently like if I change Labels 1-4 to different label names. How should I code it that I wont be using me.controls ...

Comment: How about name lables as `lab_Painter`, `lab_Dancer` ... ? I would suggest use meaningful name for all controls.

Comment: thanks. can I use something like this. `Me.Controls("lab_Carpenter" & i).Caption = cntDict(key)`  to get for Carpenter count

Comment: Almost there. I have updated the code with two options for you.

Answer (score 1):

User forms should be used to get user input and give it back, while not messing up with data (like worksheets ones)

Hence, all the preparatory work should be done in the sub that is going to call the user form and pass it the list box data

Furthermore, to add flexibility, I designed the user form's labels names as "work1" , "workEntries1", "work2" , "workEntries2", etc,
so that you need to care only about actual number of works ad not about their names

like follows (just change "UserForm1" with your actual user form class name)

```
Sub Test()

    Dim workToHoursDict As Scripting.Dictionary
        Set workToHoursDict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    Dim dataRng As Range
        Set dataRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        
        With dataRng
            Dim cel As Range
            For Each cel In .Columns(3).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Cells
                workToHoursDict(cel.Value2) = workToHoursDict(cel.Value2) + cel.Offset(, 3).Value
            Next
        End With
        
        
            With New UserForm1
            
                Dim iWork As Long
                    For iWork = 0 To workToHoursDict.Count - 1
                        With .ListBox1
                            .AddItem
                            .List(iWork, 0) = workToHoursDict.Keys(iWork)
                            .List(iWork, 1) = Format(workToHoursDict.Items(iWork), "h:mm:ss") '"[h]:mm:ss;@")
                            .List(iWork, 2) = Format(WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(dataRng.Columns(3), workToHoursDict.Keys(iWork), dataRng.Columns(6)), "h:mm:ss") ' "[h]:mm:ss;@")
                        End With
                    
                        .Controls("work" & iWork + 1).Caption = workToHoursDict.Keys(iWork)
                        .Controls("workEntries" & iWork + 1).Caption = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(dataRng.Columns(3), workToHoursDict.Keys(iWork))
                    
                    Next
                
                        .Show
                
            End With

End Sub
```